# Lapis "app.lua" and "init.lua" errors when installing Fasty CMS docker container?

Tags: lua, content-management-system, arangodb

I am attempting to install / setup Fasty CMS, following the documentation provided here: https://fasty.ovh/en/our/documentation

I have installed all necessary requirements, and have followed all outlined steps. However, I am receiving the following error when attempting to visit the "regular" view for Fasty CMS at http://demo.localhost:8080 after running the docker container:

```html
cms_1       | 2021/11/30 13:43:06 [error] 24#0: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: ./app.lua:74: cannot open git: No such file or directory
cms_1       | stack traceback:
cms_1       | coroutine 0:
cms_1       |   [C]: in function 'require'
cms_1       |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/init.lua:15: in function 'serve'
cms_1       |   content_by_lua(nginx.conf.compiled:65):2: in main chunk, client: 12.12.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "demo.localhost:8080"
```

I have setup the db_demo database in ArangoDB, and created the ~/.foxxrc file and the foxxy/app/js/config.js file, as shown below:

**.foxxrc**

```html
[server.foxxy]
url=http://localhost:8529
username=root
password=[password_here]
```

**config.js**

```html
var Config = {
  ".fasty.ovh": "https://fasty.ovh/_db/",
  /*".s1.fasty.ovh": "https://s1.fasty.ovh/_db/",
  ".s2.fasty.ovh": "https://s2.fasty.ovh/_db/"*/
};
```

I am able to login to the "admin" portal for Fasty CMS at /static/admin/, however I cannot see the regular view for the CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's missing the Lua compiled files.

Once the docker instance is ran, can you provide me the output of `docker-compose exec cms moonc **/*.moon`

Fasty frontend is written in [moonscript](https://moonscript.org/) which compile to Lua

Also, please create a `git` folder because it's needed (a new feature)

Comment: Hi @solisoft, the output of the command is:

# docker-compose exec cms moonc **/*.moon
Built applications/assets.moon
Built applications/services.moon
Built applications/uploads.moon
Built lib/aqls.moon
Built lib/arango.moon
Built lib/basic_auth.moon
Built lib/concerns.moon
Built lib/http_client.moon
Built lib/service.moon
Built lib/utils.moon
Built spec/page_spec.moon

Comment: I have also created a git folder

Comment: The doc was updated properly, thanks for the feedbacks !